# Planet where diseases are allowed to run rampant

Tags: story-identification

I read this in the UK maybe 20 years ago, I think it was part of a longer story.

Some person (I can't remember if male or female) arrives on a colony planet and immediately noticed there is dirt and disease all around, kids playing in open sewers and suchlike.

Babies die of simple childhood diseases, anyone who gets injured usually ends up dying of sepsis/infections.

The person attempts to help the populace but is told not to interfere, They are informed that the planet is undertaking a long term social experiment to try and produce humans who are immune to disease, the ones prone to germs die before they are old enough to breed.